# Repeat JUnit tests run with different setup

Tags: java, junit

For example I have some tests based on `Set<Integer>`. I want to run them with `TreeSet` and then with `HashSet`. Can I do it without manual initialization inside test method body?

Something like this:

```
public class SomeTest {
    Set<Integer> set;

    @Before 
    public void init() {
        set = new HashSet<>();
    }

//    @Before
//    public void init2() {
//        set = new TreeSet<>();
//    }

    //test...
}
```

I want to run all tests with `init()` first and then with `init2()`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cleaner approach would be:

```
public abstract class SomeTestsForSets {
  Set<Integer> set;

  @Before 
  public abstract void init();

  //test cases...
}

public class HashSetTests extends SomeTestsForSets {

  @Override
  public void init() {
    this.set = new HashSet<>();
  }
}

public class TreeSetTests extends SomeTestsForSets {

  @Override
  public void init() {
    this.set = new TreeSet<>();
  }
}
```